# Compare two folders, copy files that are different from one folder to another

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm working on this game that I have some testers playing. Due to the size of the game files, I want to create a patch which can be applied to the previous build of the game, that way my testers can "patch" the older variant and get the new variant without having to re-download the entire game. To create this patch, here's what I need to do:

Let's say I have 3 folders. `Folder 1` is an older build of the game, `Folder 2` is a newer build of the game which I will be creating the patch for, and `Folder 3` is where the files for the patch will be copied.

What I need to do is have a batch script cycle through every file in `Folder 2` and check to see if it exists in `Folder 1`. If the file doesn't exist in `Folder 1`, or the file exists but has a different hash sum, it is copied from `Folder 2` into `Folder 3`. The only problem is I have no idea how to compare files to see if they are the same in batch. I want to compare them based on hash sum and size, but not date of modification.

Comment: Check out the commands [`fc`](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) and [`comp`](http://ss64.com/nt/comp.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by his script :

```
@echo off
set "Folder1=Folder1"
set "Folder2=Folder2"
set "Folder3=Folder3"

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%folder2%"') do (
    if not exist "%folder1%\%%F" copy "%folder2%\%%F" "%folder3%" && echo Copied "%%F"
    )
pause
Exit
```

**EDIT :**

Or using **`FC`** command with **`/b`** to Perform a binary comparison

```
echo off
set "Folder1=path\to\Folder1"
set "Folder2=path\to\Folder2"
set "Folder3=path\to\Folder3"

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%folder2%"') do (
    if exist "%folder1%\%%F" (
        fc /b "%folder1%\%%F" "%folder2%\%%F"
        if "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" (
            copy "%folder2%\%%F" "%folder3%" && echo Copied "%%F"
        )
    ) else (
        copy "%folder2%\%%F" "%folder3%" && echo Copied "%%F"
    )
)
pause
Exit
```